# Implement a glow Earth with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I want to realize the earth with glow, but it is always a little different from the design drawing, because it is my first contact with three.js, so I do not know how to completely follow the design drawing to achieve, the following is my design drawing.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpLHc.png)

After modifying the map, I added a earth with glow through the shader, but the overall color was still different from the design drawing. A small part of the glow of the design drawing was covered on the earth instead of close to the edge of the earth. I do not know how to achieve this effect. As well as my implementation of the screenshot, a friend can help me modify the code?

**This is my main code**

```
var scene, camera, renderer;
var WIDTH, HEIGHT, sphere, mesh_cloud, mesh_glow; // Added mesh_glow variable
function initRender() {
  WIDTH = 1280;
  HEIGHT = 700;
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    alpha: true,
  });
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(WIDTH / HEIGHT);

  document.getElementById("box").appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}
function initScene() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
}
function initCamera() {`your text`
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 300);
}
function initLight() {
  var light = new THREE.AmbientLight("#d1d1d1", 0.6);
  scene.add(light);
  var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight("#fff", 1);
  directionalLight.position.set(-300, 300, 200);
  directionalLight.castShadow = true; // Enable shadow casting
  directionalLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 1200;
  directionalLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 1200;
  directionalLight.shadow.camera.near = 500;
  directionalLight.shadow.camera.far = 4000;
  directionalLight.shadow.camera.left = -500;
  directionalLight.shadow.camera.right = 500;
  directionalLight.shadow.camera.top = 500;
  directionalLight.shadow.camera.bottom = -500;
  scene.add(directionalLight);
}
function initObject() {
  var tmap = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
    "/resource/images/index/earth-test.svg"
  );
  var tlarmap = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
    "/resource/images/index/earth_spec.jpg"
  );
  var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(95, 95, 95);
  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
  sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  sphere.castShadow = true; // Enable shadow casting

  const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x0000, 0.5);
  scene.add(ambientLight);
  material.map = tmap;
  material.emissiveMap = tmap;
  material.emissive = new THREE.Color(0x00ffff);
  material.emissiveIntensity = 0.15;
  material.specular = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
  material.shininess = 3.5;

  // Add the larger circle (glow effect)
  var glowGeometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(95 * 1.6, 95, 95);
  var glowMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
      time: { value: 0.0 },
      innerColor: { value: new THREE.Color(0x00ffff) },
      outerColor: { value: new THREE.Color(0x00ffff) },
    },
    vertexShader: document.getElementById("vertexShader").textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById("fragmentShader").textContent,
    transparent: true,
  });

  mesh_glow = new THREE.Mesh(glowGeometry, glowMaterial);
  mesh_glow.position.set(0, 0, -5);
  scene.add(mesh_glow);
  scene.add(sphere);
}

function animation() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animation);
  renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  sphere.rotation.y += 0.004;
  // controls.update();
  mesh_glow.material.uniforms.time.value += 0.003;
}
function initStatr() {
  initRender();
  initScene();
  initCamera();
  initLight();
  initObject();
  animation();
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  initStatr();
});
```

**This is the shader code that I wrote on the html**

```
    <script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    varying vec2 vUv;
    void main() {
      vUv = uv;
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    }
  </script>
    <script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    uniform float time;
    uniform vec3 innerColor;
    uniform vec3 outerColor;
    varying vec2 vUv;
    void main() {
      float distance = length(vUv - 0.5);
      float intensity = 1.0 - smoothstep(0.3, 0.51, distance);
      vec3 color = vec3(0.4, 0.6, 1.0) * 0.98;
      gl_FragColor = vec4(color * 0.43, intensity);
    }
  </script>
```

**This is my most self-achieved effect**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgZ6Z.png)
**This is the design effect**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2vXq.png)
How can I achieve the effect of the design drawing？